# Different internet ping from two user accounts

Tags: 14.04, internet, ping

My desktop is running xubuntu 14.04 and my internet access is terrible with pings up to 9000MS. I created a new user account and I show ping speeds around 30ms, and browsing is fast. How can I find out what's wrong with my main account?

Comment: What about `/usr/sbin/traceroute` — do those results differ?

Comment: Is there difference in privileges for the user accounts ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably when the old user account is used to log in, the system launches automatically a bunch of daemons which are greedy in network resources.

Here's some command that you can run to see if there's anything unusual that pops up:

```
nethogs
netstat -anp
ps -ef 
nload
iftop
```

I recommend to try nethogs first, to see if there's anything eating your bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If the average I/O rates for nload are different between the two accounts, it is likely something loaded at login for the original account.  Nethogs or iftop can help figure out what that is.  Is this true after reboot?  Is this for outbound or inbound ping to/from some standard destination?